# Php If-Condition with Class Variables Not Working

Tags: php, variables, object, if-statement

```
class SignUp
{
      var $pass;
      var $repass;
      var $eMail;
      var $userName;

    function __construct($p,$rep,$uName,$mail)
    {
        $this->pass     = $p;
        $this->repass   = $rep;
        $this->userName = $uName;
        $this->eMail    = $mail;
    }

    public function checkData() 
    {
        if ($this->pass != $this->repass)
        {
            return 2;
        }
     }
}
```

This code doesn't seem to work and i don't know why .. It always returns 2 even when they are the same.

Here's how i call the object

```
$ch = new SignUp($_POST['password'], $_POST['repassword'], $_POST['uname'], $_POST['emailID']);
echo $ch->checkData();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that your form ha the correct name for pass and repass fields?

Comment: Should work... What does <code> if($this->pass!==$this->repass)</code> do instead of the <code>!=</code>?

Comment: Have you tried echoing the values as they are passed into the constructor to verify they are what you expect?

Comment: Before the echo $ch->checkData(); do print_r ($ch); and put it here, seems strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Variable name chaos

**Most probably the problem is caused** by what I call a very prominent code smell. You have THREE different names for each variable instead of just ONE. With so many different variable names it is easy to have one wrong and then the outcome will be what we see because one of the variables will **always be NULL**.

E.g. password is
- password
- pass
- p

etc.

Use password in every place! Same for the others.

#### Each outcome should return something

Return something (and I would return TRUE/FALSE) also in the case of equality like so:

```
if ($this->password == $this->passwordRepeat)
{
    return TRUE;
}

return FALSE;
```

#### Bad method name

Rename your method. It compares passwords, so call it `passwordsIdentical` or `comparePasswords`.

Comment: I am the down voter. While I agree with your assessment, I don't see how this fixes the problem. Chaning the variable names may improve the smell, but it doesn't change the functionality. The same is true for changing the equality test and return boolean values. None of this will fix the OPs actual problem.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but this isn't directly helpful and in any way related to the OP's problem and doesn't even attempt to answer the question or solve the problem.

Comment: The probability that one of the problems I highlight causes the issue of the OP is quite high. The code should work so we have to assume that something else is wrong. With so many different variable names it is easy to have one wrong and then the outcome will be what we see because one of the variables will always be NULL. Good practice is not a side note, it exactly avoids such problems.

Comment: My second point also points out a good practice which could have very well led to the discovery that sometimes the function actually DOES return something else than 2 but since it returns NULL, nothing is echoed.

Comment: If it returns FALSE, nothing is echoed either. But the OP said that it  always echoes 2, so it's not really relevant. The class is dead simple so  even with bad variable names and practices you can see exactly what it does, not that I am advocating it but just saying how it will not help find the problem at all.

Comment: I agree entirely with everything you wrote, but the code as written by the OP does work. The problem is more likely that the post variables don't contain what is expected.

Comment: I know about the bad practices. 
This was just a snippet of the larger thing i am trying to acheive so i just wrote quickly. And to Herbert the post variables definitely contain the expected input I double checked every one

Comment: @user1019425 why did you accept this answer? Did it fix your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could have easily isolated it to your $_POST variables not working. There is nothing wrong with the class in the sense that the comparison isn't working:

```
<?php
class SignUp{

      var $pass;
      var $repass;
      var $eMail;
      var $userName;

    function __construct($p,$rep,$uName,$mail){
        $this->pass=$p;
        $this->repass=$rep;
        $this->userName=$uName;
        $this->eMail=$mail;
    }


    public function checkData(){
        if($this->pass!=$this->repass)
        return 2;

    }
}

$a = new SignUp( "php", "notphp", "", "" );
$b = new SignUp( "php", "php", "", "" );

var_dump( $a -> checkData() );
//int(2)
var_dump( $b -> checkData() );
//NULL
var_dump( $a -> checkData() === $b -> checkData() ); 
//bool(false), they return different results.
?>
```

What does the submit form HTML look like?

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
```

/* Check this code */

```
 class SignUp{

      public $pass;
      public $repass;
      public $eMail;
      public $userName;

function __construct($p,$rep,$uName,$mail){
    $this->pass=$p;
    $this->repass=$rep;
    $this->userName=$uName;
    $this->eMail=$mail;
}


public function checkData(){
    if($this->pass!=$this->repass)
        return 2;

}



}
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

replace this

if($this->pass!=$this->repass)

to

`if(trim($this->pass) != trim($this->repass))` will work